# Get rid of iterrows in pandas loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to avoid using `iterrows()` in pandas and achieve a more performant solution. This is the code I have, where I loop through a DataFrame and for each record I need to add three more:

```
import pandas as pd

fruit_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'fruit':  ['apple','orange','pear','orange'],
    'color':  ['red','orange','green','green'],
    'weight': [5,6,3,4]
})

array = []

for index, row in fruit_data.iterrows():

    row2 = { 'fruit_2': row['fruit'], 'sequence': 0}
    array.append(row2)
    
    for i in range(2):
        row2 = { 'fruit_2': row['fruit'], 'sequence': i + 1}
        array.append(row2)

print(array)
```

My real DataFrame has millions of records. Is there a way to optimize this code and NOT use `iterrows()` or `for` loops?

Comment: what are you rtying to achieve by adding stuff froma df into a normal list? Whatfor? Pretty sure whatever you want to be done can be done differently...

Comment: @PatrickArtner this is a simplification of a more complex problem

Comment: @ps0604 You will want to post something that's more representative of the actual problem, then. Especially regarding Pandas performance, simplified problems will lead to bad solutions.

Comment: you could start with `for i in range(3): array.append({ 'fruit_2': row['fruit'], 'sequence': i })` to begin with - seems you dumbed it down too much. that wont get rid of iterrrows but at least your code gets more concise - then try to describe the "what" not the "how" you tried to accomplish it - I am pretty sure that approach is already flawed.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the original problem that you are trying to solve? What are you trying to accomplish by building a list of dictionaries from the dataframe? Why don't you use the dataframe directly to solve this problem? If you don't know how to answer the last question, we can probably give suggestions once you answer the other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `repeat` to repeat each fruit 3 times; then `groupby` + `cumcount` to assign `sequence` numbers; finally `to_dict` for the final output:

```
tmp = fruit_data['fruit'].repeat(3).reset_index(name='fruit_2')
tmp['sequence'] = tmp.groupby('index').cumcount()
out = tmp.drop(columns='index').to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
[{'fruit_2': 'apple', 'sequence': 0},
 {'fruit_2': 'apple', 'sequence': 1},
 {'fruit_2': 'apple', 'sequence': 2},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 0},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 1},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 2},
 {'fruit_2': 'pear', 'sequence': 0},
 {'fruit_2': 'pear', 'sequence': 1},
 {'fruit_2': 'pear', 'sequence': 2},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 0},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 1},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 2}]
```

Comment: Nice! One-liner: `fruit_data['fruit'].repeat(3).reset_index(name='fruit_2').pipe(lambda x: x.assign(sequence=x.groupby('index').cumcount())).drop(columns='index').to_dict('records')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
array = (
    fruit_data['fruit']
    .repeat(3)
    .to_frame(name='fruit_2')
    .set_index(np.tile(np.arange(3), len(fruit_data['fruit'])))
    .reset_index()
    .rename({'index':'sequence'},axis=1)
    [['fruit_2', 'sequence']]
    .to_dict('records')
)
```

Output:

```
>>> array
[{'fruit_2': 'apple', 'sequence': 0},
 {'fruit_2': 'apple', 'sequence': 1},
 {'fruit_2': 'apple', 'sequence': 2},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 0},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 1},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 2},
 {'fruit_2': 'pear', 'sequence': 0},
 {'fruit_2': 'pear', 'sequence': 1},
 {'fruit_2': 'pear', 'sequence': 2},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 0},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 1},
 {'fruit_2': 'orange', 'sequence': 2}]
```